# Remove certain character within a pattern of text

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a folder with markdown files containing text with citekeys in the Pandoc format `[@Name:2021]`. I decided to remove the colons from my citekeys and would like to automatically delete them in my markdown files. The citekeys can have the following form:

```
[@Name:2021]
[@Name:2021, 10]
[@Name:Title]
[Vgl. @Name:2021]
[Vgl. @Name:2021, 20--30]
```

So they should become:

```
[@Name2021]
[@Name2021, 10]
[@NameTitle]
[Vgl. @Name2021]
[Vgl. @Name2021, 20--30]
```

Some citekeys that I added recently do not contain colons already. And there might also be some footnotes in the format `^[Text]` containing colons that should not be deleted, of course.

Is there any command/script of command line utilities that would allow me to remove the colons in the citekeys all markdown files automatically? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perl is handy here: the replacement part of `s///` can be evaluated as code:

```bsh
perl -pe 's/\[[^]]*@.+?\]/ ($cite = $&) =~ s{:}{}g; $cite /ge' file
```

outputs

```
[@Name2021]
[@Name2021, 10]
[@NameTitle]
[Vgl. @Name2021]
[Vgl. @Name2021, 20--30]
```

If you're happy with the output, you can save the changes back to the file with

```bsh
perl -i -pe ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` and applying a global substitution of type `'s/regexp/replacement/g'` in-place (`-i`) to all non-hidden files in the current directory:

```
sed -i -- 's/\(\[[^]@]*@[^]:]*\):\([^]]*\]\)/\1\2/g' *
```

- `s/` start substitution
- `\(` open first capturing group

  - `\[` match literal `[`
  - `[^]@]*` match any non-`]` and non-`@` characters
  - `@` match literal `@`
  - `[^]:]*` match any non-`]` and non-`:` characters
- `\)` close first capturing group
- `:` match literal `:`
- `\(` open second capturing group

  - `[^]]*` match any non-`]` characters
  - `\]` match literal `]`
- `\)` close second capturing group
- `/` replacement separator
- `\1\2` replacement string containing the captured groups
- `/g` end substitution, replace `g`lobally

Create a backup of the target directory before running this command or change `-i` to `-i'.bak'` to keep a copy of
the original files with suffix `.bak`. Use a diff tool of your choice to compare the original files with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If the only lines you don't want to change are those that start with `^`, I think this command would do the trick:

```
sed '/^\^/!s/://' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -lpe 'my($p1, $p2);
    substr($_, $p1, $p2-$p1) =~ s/(@[^:]+):/$1/
      while
        $p1 = 1+index($_, "[", $p2)
                 and
        $p2 = 1+index($_, "]", $p1);
' file
```

- $p1/$p2 are the positions of `[` and a `]` following it.
- substr() is then passed the beginning of chunk + chunk length and the s/// command operates upon this chunk and the current record $_ is updated too.

Output:

```
@Name2021]
[@Name2021, 10]
[@NameTitle]
[Vgl. @Name2021]
[Vgl. @Name2021, 20--30]
```